# Awesomium - How to get only source code?

Tags: c#, awesomium

I have a C# project. I use Awesomium webbrowser. I want to get only the source code of any url. Because i don't need to show the page content in my program. If i could do this, i will save time. Is it any possibilities for that?

Comment: You mean like `HttpWebRequest` / `WebClient` / `HttpClient`?

Comment: If you're not planning to show page content in your application - then you don't need Awesomium at all. You can get page source with `WebClient` or `HttpRequest` + `HttpResponse`

Comment: then why you need to use Awesomium?

Comment: Because i have to login into the webpage. Otherwise i can't call the url.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get source of loaded page into Awesomium's webControl, you can do this with `webControl.HTML` property, but you need to wait till document is loaded: `DocumentReadyState.Loaded`

Or you can see what is between `html` tags: `webControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML");`